# Keep getting [object, Object] from array for $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting [object, Object] from array for $.each when i try and alert it. 
Below is the code I am using, I have tried several different ways but this seems to be the way that works the best.

Could someone please help me out

```
var min_chats = [];

$(function () {
    $(".append_chat").click(function () {
        var chatid = $(this).attr('alt');
        var data = $(this).attr('data');
        min_chats.push({
            "chatid": chatid,
            "data": data
        });
    });

    $("#max_close").live("click", function () {
        var chatid = $(this).attr('alt');
        var data = $(this).attr('data');

        $.each(min_chats, function (key, val) {
            alert(key + val);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback parameters for `$.each` are index and value, not key and value.

In your case `key` will contain the index of the array and `val` will contain your object containing 2 properties: `chatid` and `data`.

So your code should look like:

```
$.each(min_chats, function(index, val) {
    alert(val.chatid + val.data);
});
```

`$.each` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: $.each(min_chats, function(index,value) {
            alert(index+value);
        });

Comment: the index shows up but the value is just object Object

Comment: Did you see the answer? And what value does `data` have? Is it a string or object?